# OpenCV IP Camera RTSP stream

Tags: java, opencv, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm trying to access a RTSP video stream from an IP camera using OpenCV and Java. I can access the stream using VLC player with the following format: `rtsp://192.168.1.10:554/rtsp_live0` but when I try to use OpenCV the video stream seems to always be closed.

The code I'm using... (simplified)

```
VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture();
capture.open("rtsp://192.168.1.10:554/rtsp_live0");
while(!capture.isOpened())
    System.out.print("Not opened :( \r");
```

I have a Mustcam H806P and found the stream URI from this website: http://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=ipcamera

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you compile `opencv` with `libav` or `gstreamer` support?

Comment: @victor1234 when I tried yesterday I was using Windows so I didn't have to complile from source. I am now back on my Linux machine so I'll try to compile opencv with libav

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 4):

I'm reporting Alexander Smorkalov [answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/11299/how-to-open-rtsp-videostream-from-ip-cam/?answer=11326#post-id-11326) on *answers.opencv.org*

> OpenCV uses ffmpeg library for video I/O. Try to get video stream with console ffmpeg tool. The address must be the same.

See also here [OpenCV - how to capture rtsp video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041370/opencv-how-to-capture-rtsp-video-stream)

Comment: Using ffmpeg I was able to get the video stream and save it. I'm starting to think its something to do with me not properly linking the ffmpeg libraries.